# Make java code in android apk file inaccessible (not just obfuscated)

Tags: java, obfuscation, copy-protection

Recently I was asked to a job interview from a potential employer because of an android app I'm currently developing that caught his attention. It is not finished yet and so it is not uploaded to google play store. In this app I do something that is new and original and doesn't allready exist in any other app play store. Now...he asked me to give him the apk in order to test it and see for him self how good and reliable it is.

I'm having second thoughts about doing that as I'm not really a fan of the idea of giving my hard to produce code to a stranger..It could easily be stolen once someone has the apk file and since it is not allready on play store, the originality of the app goes bye-bye..

QUESTION: Is there any way to make the code of the app inaccessible (not just hard to read) so that I'm safe from that possibility?

I know about obfuscation and while it's a good step it's not tottaly safe. With enough patience and tools someone could still get your code. Given the fact that this particular protected apk will not be uploaded to google play but will be given hand to hand are there other techniques to block access to the code?

Comment: Have a lawyer prepare a non disclosure agreement, and have him sign and notarize it.

Comment: If it can be executed it can be accessed it can be reverse engineered. Period. All one can do is making reverse engineering as hard as possible - by obfuscation etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not Really...

By **.apk** file he can easily get layout (.XML files) as well as all .class files by the use of reverse Engineering.

Even if he get all your code it will take much time to interpret your code

So better to upload it on PlayStore.